# How to substitute placeholders in string with arguments?

Tags: macros, strings, substitution

I'm writing a document in two languages using the macro `\enzh` defined as below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifen
\entrue % comment out to switch to Chinese
\newcommand{\enzh}[2]{\ifen#1\else#2\fi}

\begin{document}

\enzh{English text}{Chinese text}

\end{document}
```

It currently shows "English text", and if `\entrue` is commented out it shows "Chinese text".  This part is working as intented.

However, there may be elements common to both languages. Instead of repeating the same code for both languages, I wish to substitute placeholders in the strings of the two languages with these common elements, using a syntax similar to how Python string's `format`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newif\ifen
\entrue % comment out to switch to Chinese
\newcommand{\enzh}[2]{\ifen#1\else#2\fi} % how should this command be implemented?

\begin{document}

\enzh{English #1 text #2}{Chinese #2 text #1}{\href{https://www.google.com}{Google}}{b}

\end{document}
```

Should show "English [Google](https://www.google.com) text b" and "Chinese b text [Google](https://www.google.com)" for the two language modes. Ideally arbitrarily many substitutions could be made, but for my purposes, 3 should be enough.

How should the command `\enzh` be implemented for this be achieved?

Comment: Best look at the translator package, which is used by Beamer and is suitable for what you need and better structured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using expl3 you can define a command `\MyReplace` which takes three arguments,

1. ⟨English text⟩
2. ⟨Chinese text⟩
3. ⟨List of common text phrases that in English/Chinese text replace {1}, {2}, {3},…⟩

, which actually hold lists of brace-nested undelimited arguments.

Depending on whether `\englishtrue` or `\englishfalse` iteration takes place on the undelimited arguments either of the ⟨English text⟩ or of the ⟨Chinese text⟩, whereby each element is treated as follows:

- In case its first token is `:` it is assumed that it denotes a non-common text phrase and it is delivered with the `:` removed.
- In case its first token is not `:` it is assumed that it denotes a number k and the k<sup>th</sup> element of the ⟨List of common text phrases⟩ is delivered if that list has a k<sup>th</sup> element.

At first I considered doing it the other way round, i.e. `:⟨number⟩` instead of `:⟨non-common text phrase⟩`, but then the question arises of how to handle the case of a non-common text phrase having a leading `:` and not erroneously being passed on to the treatment as a :⟨number⟩ which might lead to low-level TeX error-messages.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \l_english_bool
\cs_new_protected:Npn \englishtrue {\bool_set_true:N \l_english_bool}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \englishfalse {\bool_set_false:N \l_english_bool}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \enzh #1#2 {\bool_if:nTF \l_english_bool {#1}{#2}}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \MyReplace #1#2#3
  {
    \bool_if:nTF \l_english_bool
    {\tl_map_tokens:nn {#1} }
    {\tl_map_tokens:nn {#2} }
    {\mymodule_get_kth_arg:nn{#3}}
  }
\cs_new:Nx \mymodule_get_kth_arg:nn
  {
    \exp_not:N\tl_if_blank:nF {#2} {
      \exp_not:N\tl_if_head_eq_meaning:nNTF 
         {#2}\token_to_str:N :
         {\exp_not:N\tl_tail:n {#2}}
         {\exp_not:N\tl_item:nn{#1}{#2}}
    }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\englishtrue

\enzh{English text}{Chinese text}

\MyReplace{ {1}{: }{2}{: English text A }{2}{: English text B }{5}{: English text C }{4}{: English text D }{3} }%
          { {2}{: }{1}{: Chinese Text text A }{1}{: Chinese text B }{3}{: Chinese Text text C }{4}{: Chinese text D }{5} }%
          { 
             {Common Phrase 1} 
             {Common Phrase 2}
             {Common Phrase 3}
             {Common Phrase 4}
             {Common Phrase 5}
          }

\bigskip

\englishfalse

\enzh{English text}{Chinese text}

\MyReplace{ {1}{: }{2}{: English text A }{2}{: English text B }{5}{: English text C }{4}{: English text D }{3} }%
          { {2}{: }{1}{: Chinese Text text A }{1}{: Chinese text B }{3}{: Chinese Text text C }{4}{: Chinese text D }{5} }%
          { 
             {Common Phrase 1}
             {Common Phrase 2}
             {Common Phrase 3}
             {Common Phrase 4}
             {Common Phrase 5}
          }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Both in the ⟨English text⟩ and in the ⟨Chinese text⟩ of the example above `{: }` is used for having a space as a non-common text phrase. Instead you could as well have the space as another common text phrase and do

```latex
\MyReplace{ {1}{6}{2}{: English text A }{2}{: English text B }{5}{: English text C }{4}{: English text D }{3} }%
          { {2}{6}{1}{: Chinese Text text A }{1}{: Chinese text B }{3}{: Chinese Text text C }{4}{: Chinese text D }{5} }%
          { 
             {Common Phrase 1}
             {Common Phrase 2}
             {Common Phrase 3}
             {Common Phrase 4}
             {Common Phrase 5}
             { }
          }
```

---

---

If you prefer denoting common text phrases/replacements via `#1`, `#2`, ..., `#11`, ... instead of `{1}`, `{2}`, ..., `{11}`, ... , and if expandability is not an issue, you can probably do with regular expressions of l3regex.

With the following example, the regexp is to search for `#` trailed by a sequence of digits `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, trailed by one optional slash `/` so that you can separate digits belonging to the number of the element of the list of common text phrases/replacements from digits belonging to the text that shall be delivered—thus, if you wish a slash to occur in the text right behind a common text phrase/right behind a replacement denoted by `#⟨sequence of digits denoting the number of the common text phrase/replacement⟩`, you need to type two slashes:
`#⟨sequence of digits denoting the number of the common text phrase/replacement⟩//The second one of these slashes goes into the text. The first one is removed as "digit"-separator"`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \l_english_bool
\tl_new:N \l_mymodule_replacementlist_tl
\tl_new:N \l_mymodule_textphrase_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \englishtrue {\bool_set_true:N \l_english_bool}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \englishfalse {\bool_set_false:N \l_english_bool}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \enzh #1#2 {\bool_if:nTF \l_english_bool {#1}{#2}}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \MyReplace #1#2#3
  {
    \bool_if:nTF \l_english_bool
    {\tl_set:Nn\l_mymodule_textphrase_tl {#1} }
    {\tl_set:Nn\l_mymodule_textphrase_tl {#2} }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_mymodule_replacementlist_tl {#3}
    % \cA. denotes any active character; \cC. denotes any control sequence token, 
    % so the following prepends \noexpand to tokens that might be expandable:
    \regex_replace_all:nnN {(?:\cA.|\cC.)}{\c{exp\_not\:N}\0}\l_mymodule_textphrase_tl
%    \tl_show:N \l_mymodule_textphrase_tl
    % Replace any #<digit sequence><optional slash> of category 6 that is preceeded by an even amount of hashes 
    % by \tl_\item:Nn \l_mymodule_replacementlist_tl {<digit sequence>}:
    \regex_replace_all:nnN {  ((?:\G|[^\cP.])(?:[\cP.][\cP.])*)  [\cP.]   (\cO[\d]+)\cO\/?  }
                           {\1 \c{tl\_item\:Nn} \c{l\_mymodule\_replacementlist\_tl} \cB\{ \2 \cE\}}
                           \l_mymodule_textphrase_tl
%    \tl_show:N \l_mymodule_textphrase_tl
    % Expand the token list to get the token-list-items and halve doubled hashes:
    \exp_args:NNx \tl_set:Nn \l_mymodule_textphrase_tl {\tl_use:N \l_mymodule_textphrase_tl }
%    \tl_show:N \l_mymodule_textphrase_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_mymodule_textphrase_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\englishtrue

\MyReplace{\section{#1 English text #2}}
          {\section{#2 Chinese text #1}}
          {
             {Common 1} % <- this is #1
             {Common 2} % <- this is #2
          }

\enzh{English text}{Chinese text}

\bigskip

\MyReplace{#1 #2 English text A #2//English text B #5 English text C #4 English text D #3/7 is a nice digit.}%
          {#2 #1 Chinese Text text A #1//Chinese text B #3 Chinese Text text C #4 Chinese text D #5/7 is a nice digit.}%
          { 
             {Common Phrase 1} % <- this is #1
             {Common Phrase 2} % <- this is #2
             {Common Phrase 3} % <- this is #3
             {Common Phrase 4} % <- this is #4
             {Common Phrase 5} % <- this is #5
          }

\bigskip

\MyReplace{\def\MACRO##1##2{#1 English text #2}}%
          {\def\MACRO##1##2{#2 Chinese text #1}}%
          { 
             {Common Phrase 1, Argument 1: #1, Argument 2: #2} % <- in the two arguments above this is #1
             {Common Phrase 2, Argument 1: #1, Argument 2: #2} % <- in the two arguments above this is #2
          }%
{\tt\frenchspacing\string\MACRO: \meaning\MACRO}

\englishfalse

\MyReplace{\section{#1 English text #2}}
          {\section{#2 Chinese text #1}}
          {
             {Common 1} % <- this is #1
             {Common 2} % <- this is #2
          }

\enzh{English text}{Chinese text}

\bigskip

\MyReplace{#1 #2 English text A #2//English text B #5 English text C #4 English text D #3/7 is a nice digit.}%
          {#2 #1 Chinese Text text A #1//Chinese text B #3 Chinese Text text C #4 Chinese text D #5/7 is a nice digit.}%
          { 
             {Common Phrase 1} % <- this is #1
             {Common Phrase 2} % <- this is #2
             {Common Phrase 3} % <- this is #3
             {Common Phrase 4} % <- this is #4
             {Common Phrase 5} % <- this is #5
          }

\bigskip

\MyReplace{\def\MACRO##1##2{#1 English text #2}}%
          {\def\MACRO##1##2{#2 Chinese text #1}}%
          { 
             {Common Phrase 1, Argument 1: #1, Argument 2: #2} % <- in the two arguments above this is #1
             {Common Phrase 2, Argument 1: #1, Argument 2: #2} % <- in the two arguments above this is #2
          }%
{\tt\frenchspacing\string\MACRO: \meaning\MACRO}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you do it this way and use `\MyReplace` as a component of the replacement text/of the ⟨balanced text⟩ of the ⟨definition⟩ of a macro, the hashes `#` denoting the numbers of the common text phrases/replacements need to be doubled in the same way in which hashes denoting parameters need to be doubled when nesting a ⟨definition⟩ inside a ⟨definition⟩.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply define `\enzhi` for single parameter, `\enzhii` for two parameters etc.

```
\newif\ifen
\entrue

\def\enzh#1#2{\ifen#1\else#2\fi}
\def\enzhi#1#2{\def\tmp##1{\ifen#1\else#2\fi}\tmp}
\def\enzhii#1#2{\def\tmp##1##2{\ifen#1\else#2\fi}\tmp}

\enzhii{English #1 text #2}{Chinese #2 text #1}{\href{https://www.google.com}{Google}}{b}
```

Comment: This is a good solution for the OP's question. IMHO though one should use an approach to `gettext` where there is always a keyword say hello{chinese text} hello{italian text} and just input the right language file.  This is how normally one would do UI i18N keywords.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is to have a consistent syntax, so I propose that `\enzh` has two trailing optional arguments. If they're present, the two mandatory ones are interpreted as templates (where you can use `#1` and `#2`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\enzh}{mmoO{#3}}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
   {% no optional arguments
    \legacy_if:nTF { en } { #1 } { #2 }
   }
   {% with optional arguments
    \tian_enzh:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tian_enzh:nnnn
 {
  \group_begin:
  \legacy_if:nTF { en }
   {% en is true, use the first argument as template
    \cs_set:Nn \__tian_enzh_do:nn { #1 }
   }
   {% en is false, use the second argument as template
    \cs_set:Nn \__tian_enzh_do:nn { #2 }
   }
  % do the job
  \__tian_enzh_do:nn { #3 } { #4 }
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__tian_enzh_do:nn {} % initialize the auxiliary function

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newif\ifen

\begin{document}

\section{Chinese}

\enzh{English text}{Chinese text}

\enzh{English #1 text #2}{Chinese #2 text #1}[\href{https://www.google.com}{Google}][b]

\section{English}
\entrue

\enzh{English text}{Chinese text}

\enzh{English #1 text #2}{Chinese #2 text #1}[\href{https://www.google.com}{Google}][b]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If just one optional argument, the second one is taken to be the same as the one that appears.